# HtmlUnit net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "GetLoginJsonInfo" from undefined

Tags: javascript, java, exception, htmlunit

My code like this:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(100000);
HtmlPage page = null;
try {
    page = webClient.getPage("http://www.iqiyi.com/a_19rrharlvd.html");
    HtmlAnchor ha = page.getFirstByXPath("//a[@data-avlist-page='2']");
    page = ha.click();
    saveStringToFile("E://abcHtml.txt", page.asXml());
} catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
webClient.closeAllWindows();
```

And I run this project, then it throws some js exceptions and the ha.click() do not work( I get the file is same to not do ha.click()). Exceptions like that:

```
net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "GetLoginJsonInfo" from undefined (http://static.iqiyi.com/js/pingback/qa.js#1)
   .....
 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.DefaultJavaScriptExecutor.run(DefaultJavaScriptExecutor.java:162)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
== CALLING JAVASCRIPT ==
function () {
  var t = o + "#" + e + "=" + i;
  try {
      window.JSHandler.logToConsole("xxx");
  }
  catch (n) {
      if (!window.external.GetLoginJsonInfo) {
          r.iframeRequest(t);
      }
  }
}
======= EXCEPTION END ========
```

Now, what can i do to let it no care the js exception, and run click function?
I try other page, if it don't throw exceptions, the function of click is work.But when the exceptions to be throw, it will do no work...
**--------------------------------------------Dividing line---------------------------------------------------**
***Thank you for help. When I change htmlUnit version to 2.25, this exception be solved. But it throw a new exception like that***:

```
Enclosed exception: 
net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EvaluatorException: missing ; before statement (http://nlwl.iqiyi.com/apis/urc/getqd?authcookie=null&containsUgc=1&agent_type=1&subTypes=1%2C7%2C9&channelIds=1%2C2&callback=window.Q.__callbacks__.cbd1dmvj#1)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter.error(StrictErrorReporter.java:65)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.addError(Parser.java:188)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.addError(Parser.java:167)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.reportError(Parser.java:255)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.reportError(Parser.java:244)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.reportError(Parser.java:237)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.autoInsertSemicolon(Parser.java:1089)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.statementHelper(Parser.java:1066)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.statement(Parser.java:928)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.statements(Parser.java:888)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.block(Parser.java:1701)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.statementHelper(Parser.java:1032)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.statement(Parser.java:928)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.parse(Parser.java:572)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.parse(Parser.java:492)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.compileImpl(Context.java:2660)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.compileString(Context.java:1623)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory$TimeoutContext.compileString(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:184)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.compileString(Context.java:1615)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$2.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:709)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:879)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:628)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:515)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.compile(JavaScriptEngine.java:718)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.compile(JavaScriptEngine.java:683)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadJavaScriptFromUrl(HtmlPage.java:1069)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadExternalJavaScriptFile(HtmlPage.java:966)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:352)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$2.execute(HtmlScript.java:239)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.doProcessPostponedActions(JavaScriptEngine.java:939)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.access$500(JavaScriptEngine.java:100)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:889)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:628)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:515)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:824)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:796)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunctionIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:2454)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventListenersContainer.executeEventHandler(EventListenersContainer.java:298)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventListenersContainer.executeListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:383)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventTarget.executeEventLocally(EventTarget.java:107)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeEvent(HtmlScript.java:379)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:354)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$2.execute(HtmlScript.java:239)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.doProcessPostponedActions(JavaScriptEngine.java:939)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.access$500(JavaScriptEngine.java:100)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:889)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:628)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:515)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:824)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:796)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunctionIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:2454)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventListenersContainer.executeEventHandler(EventListenersContainer.java:298)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventListenersContainer.executeListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:383)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventTarget.executeEventLocally(EventTarget.java:107)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeEvent(HtmlScript.java:379)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:354)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$2.execute(HtmlScript.java:239)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.doProcessPostponedActions(JavaScriptEngine.java:939)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.access$500(JavaScriptEngine.java:100)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:889)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:628)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:515)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:824)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:796)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunctionIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:2454)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventListenersContainer.executeEventHandler(EventListenersContainer.java:298)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventListenersContainer.executeListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:383)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventTarget.executeEventLocally(EventTarget.java:107)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeEvent(HtmlScript.java:379)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:354)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$2.execute(HtmlScript.java:239)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.doProcessPostponedActions(JavaScriptEngine.java:939)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.access$500(JavaScriptEngine.java:100)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:889)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:628)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:515)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:775)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:751)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:739)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:910)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeInlineScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:307)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:368)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$2.execute(HtmlScript.java:239)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:258)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:781)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:738)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1243)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1143)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:226)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:345)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3154)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2117)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:945)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:521)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:472)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:988)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:246)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:188)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:267)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:155)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:517)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:391)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:309)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:456)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:441)
    at TestMain.main(TestMain.java:42)
== CALLING JAVASCRIPT ==
{"code":"A00101","come":"no_uid","count":0,"data":{}}
======= EXCEPTION END ========
```

Is not what I have ignored some conditions? May be like support the json format?

Comment: `window.external` is undefined. Pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: So I think if can let WebClient not care this exception and continue. The function of click may be work. Now I don't know how to ignore this exception when using HtmlUnit.

Comment: Do you use the latest HtmlUnit version? window.external is supported as far as i can see.

Comment: yes..thank you for help, i get latest version. it can work, but there are new exception:Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EvaluatorException: missing ;

Answer (score 1):

Have done a quick check; your code works without any problems with version 2.25 (as long as saveStringToFile does not do anything special).

Comment: yes..thank you~ it can work, but there are other exception.

Comment: saveStringToFile only put html sourcecode into a file.

Comment: I was having an issue where `HtmlUnit` was throwing `com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.UniqueTag cannot be cast to net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.BaseFunction` when I use `client.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true)`, and thanks to this answer I tested `HtmlUnit 2.25` and it worked. This issue affect version 2.28 and 2.29 as well. I'm using 2.27 ftw!

Comment: Please open an HtmlUnit issue and provide some more details (the url you are using, and the complete stack trace).